# Why window.open remove params from query?

Tags: javascript, angular, redirect

I have some strange case in my angular app. I would like to redirect to another tab with params. Code below works only local in dev version, build via

```
npm start
```

But when I build prod version and host on my server window.open redirects but without params, it removes '?' query params and value.
    ng build --prod

```
const url = this.router.serializeUrl(this.router.createUrlTree(['/employee'], {queryParams :{selectId:someID}}));
window.open(url,'_blank');
```

Comment: What value does `url` contain?

Comment: e.g. /employee?selectId=abc123

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the case here but I had the same issue and the solution was add a slash before the param:

```
 /employee/?selectId=abc123
```